# How to rewrite to an url

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

In IIS url rewriting it's able to do rewrite to another url doing the following:

```
 <rule name="Blog" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="(?:^blog|weblog)(?:/)?(.*)" /> 
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.domain.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" /> 
</rule>
```

So the url when the url domain.com/blog is called the call is rewriten to blog.domain.com (but the url in the browser stays the same).

How would I accomplish the same within C# code?

I have the HttpContext, but then I can only redirect. There is an RewritePath method but giving an url as parameter results in a "not a valid virtual path" exception.

Comment: seems just sort of regex replace?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether its called rewriting however the act is like rewriting an url. simple, just create a webrequest, get the response of the webrequest and return the result as the html to the webpage.

If you are using ASP.Net MVC this might be helpful,

```
public virtual ActionResult RealUrl()
        {
          var request = WebRequest.Create("http://rewriteUrl.com/blahblah");
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        if (dataStream == null) return null;
        var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return Content(responseFromServer); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your looking for a proxy solution: https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing

Comment: Indeed, that's how it's currently working with the IIS rewrite configuration. But I want to do the same thing in code only, how would I need to call it then?

Comment: The above answers is how I would do it... Its not perfect, as your basically replicating proxy functionality. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/42644178/1381426)